# Finding the sides of a $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle with hypotenuse $7\sqrt{3}$

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone help me solve this question and how to solve it? It has multiple ways to solve, but I would like to know the best way.

This question isn't mine but was asked by a friend of mine.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or using techniques with which you are unfamiliar. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Comments are easily overlooked, so [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3409633/edit) to add clarifications.

Comment: What's the ratio of $a$ and $b$ in terms of some trigonometric formula?

Comment: What should you do to hypotenuse to get smallest side?

Answer (score 4):

I want to address

> I would like to know the best way [to solve this problem].

There is no "best way" to solve a problem. Different ways start from different assumptions about what you already know. Some  generalize, some are specific to the particular problem at hand. Some are short and clever (even mysterious), others longer and more transparent.

Asking for "best" is not a mathematical question. The answer is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thank you Ethan, I really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(30)= \frac{b}{7\sqrt{3}}$
And since $\sin(30) = \frac{1}{2}$ follows that: $a = \frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2}$

And $b$ can be calculated using the Pythagoras form; where:
(hypotenuse)$^2 = a^2 + b^2$

So: 
$(7\sqrt{3})^2 = (\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2})^2  + b^2$ 
$b^2 = (7\sqrt{3})^2 - (\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{2})^2$ 
$b^2 = (7\sqrt{3})^2 - \frac{(7\sqrt{3})^2}{4} $
$b^2 = 49\cdot3 - \frac{49\cdot3}{4}$
$b^2 = 147 - \frac{147}{4}$
$b^2 = 147 - 36.75 = 110.25$ 
$b = \sqrt{110.25} = 10.5$

Cheers!

Comment: $\sin(30)={a\over 7\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Thank you Roddy, I looked over your method and fully understood how to do it. I really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

$30,60,90$ degrees .. there is an equilateral triangle somewhere .. can you find it ? can you determine the ratio of one side to the hypothenuse ?

Comment: Thank you G Cab, I saw that afterwords that all I had to do to find a was to divide c by 2. I really appreciate your time and effort.